# Incorrect table row number announce on Talkback

Tags: android, html, wai-aria, talkback

I have created a simple table with multiple row, and also inside the table, I have defined tab panel inside which we have more rows.

```html
    <div role="table" aria-label="Semantic Elements" aria-describedby="semantic_elements_table_desc" aria-rowcount="81">
      <div id="semantic_elements_table_desc">Semantic Elements to use instead of ARIA's roles</div>
      <div role="rowgroup">
         <div role="row">
           <span role="columnheader" aria-sort="none">ARIA Role</span>
           <span role="columnheader" aria-sort="none">Semantic Element</span>
         </div>
       </div>
       <div role="rowgroup">
        <div role="row" aria-rowindex="11">
           <span role="cell">header</span>
           <span role="cell">h1</span>
        </div>
        <div role="tablist">
        <div role="tab">
          <button>Hello</button>
        </div>
        <div role="tabpanel">
        <div role="row"  aria-rowindex="16">
          <span role="cell">header</span>
          <span role="cell">h6</span>
        </div>
        <div role="row"  aria-rowindex="18">
          <span role="cell">rowgroup</span>
          <span role="cell">thead</span>
        </div>
        <div role="row"  aria-rowindex="24">
          <span role="cell">term</span>
          <span role="cell">dt</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Now when I listen to each row on Talkback, rows inside the tablist announce the wrong row number (only announce row 1 col 1) , what went wrong here? How can I achieve the correct row number inside tabpanel.

Answer (score 0):

I would start by cleaning up the code a bit.  You have some parent/child relationships that are not correct.  Your structure looks like this:

```
table
  rowgroup
    row
      columnheader
      columnheader
  rowgroup
    row
      cell
      cell
    tablist
      tab
      tabpanel
        row
        row
        row
```

A `rowgroup` can only contain `row` elements as direct children.  See "Required Owned Elements" in https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/#rowgroup.  So having a `tablist` as a child of a `rowgroup` is not valid.

Your `tablist` also isn't structured correctly.  Child elements of a `tablist` are only allowed to be `tab` elements.  You have the `tablpanel` as a child too, which is not valid.

And then your `row` elements in the `tabpanel`, which are the specific elements you were asking about, don't have a parent of `table` or `rowgroup`.  The parent is a `tabpanel` which is going to confuse the screen reader.

I'm not sure what the final result you're trying to achieve, but the table must have proper parent/child relationships for them to be read correctly.  You're close but are mixing a couple objects together.  You can have a tablist in a table cell but you can't have it in the middle of the table rows.

You need something like this:

```
table
  rowgroup
    row
      columnheader
      columnheader
  rowgroup
    row
      cell
      cell
    row
      cell
        tablist
          tab
          tab
          tab
        tabpanel
        tabpanel
        tabpanel
      cell
    row
      cell
      cell
```

Comment: thanks for the response, my data is inside tab panel which I need as a row, is that possible we can achieve that as a row?